# Formatting Numbers in SwiftUI TextField

Tags: swiftui

In SwiftUI how can I make sure that a TextField only displays numbers like year 2023 without commas. Also the year State variable is going to be optional. If I use the year formatter I implemented below then the year is always nil in the isFormValid property.

```
static var year: NumberFormatter {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.groupingSeparator = ""
        return formatter
    }


 @State private var year: Int?
    
    private var isFormValid: Bool {
        !title.isEmptyOrWhiteSpace && year != nil
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Title", text: $title)
            TextField("Year", value: $year, formatter: NumberFormatter.year)
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)